# Loop sum in asp.net c# using sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have made a solution for sale.

There is ID of clients associated.for every ID there is a amount which is charged every day.
table is like

```
ID     AMOUNT  Date 
-------------------------
HD001  20      1/01/2014
HD002  20      1/01/2014 
HD003  20      1/01/2014
HD004  20      1/01/2014
HD005  20      1/01/2014
HD006  20      1/01/2014
HD007  20      1/01/2014
HD001  20      2/01/2014
HD002  20      2/01/2014
HD003  20      2/01/2014
HD004  20      2/01/2014
HD005  20      2/01/2014
HD006  20      2/01/2014
HD007  20      2/01/2014
HD001  20      3/01/2014
HD002  20      3/01/2014
HD003  20      3/01/2014
HD004  20      3/01/2014
HD005  20      3/01/2014
HD006  20      3/01/2014
HD007  20      3/01/2014
.
.
.
HD001  20      31/01/2014
HD002  20      31/01/2014
HD003  20      31/01/2014
HD004  20      31/01/2014
HD005  20      31/01/2014
HD006  20      31/01/2014
HD007  20      31/01/2014
```

I have to display the result as (for DATE between 1/01/2014 and 31/01/2014)

```
ID     SUM     
-----------    
HD001  620
HD002  620
HD003  620
HD004  620
HD005  620
HD006  620
HD007  620
```

So kindly help me getting this from single query

I know about single outcome but getting combined result is tough

My code for single output is

```
select SUM(convert(float, total)) 
from buffalo_milk_sale 
where  clientid between 'HD001' AND 'HD099'  
       AND date_ between '01/08/2014' and '30/08/2014';
```

Comment: And this produces an error? The wrong value? Runs forever?  We need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the client ID in order to get the correct sum for each. To display the results you will also need to select the client ID. All together you have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT 
    clientid AS [ID]
    ,SUM(convert(float, total)) AS [SUM]
FROM 
    buffalo_milk_sale 
WHERE 
    clientid BETWEEN 'HD001' AND 'HD099' 
    AND 
    date_ BETWEEN '01/08/2014' and '30/08/2014'
GROUP BY
    clientid
```